# Entity-Framework what is the difference between Migrations Seed and ContextInitializer Seed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5

I am learning EF in school and I'm currently working with EF 5, MVC 5, I can't get my head around the Migrations and ContextInitializer. 
I am following this [guide](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/using-web-api-1-with-entity-framework-5/using-web-api-with-entity-framework-part-1) because I find it more suited for my project. I did read and almost build the updated [guide](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3) but, because I'm using a slightly older EF5, I couldn't get it working.
My question is: In the newer, EF6 guide, there is this Migrations.cs which has a Seed method, in the older EF5 guide, the Seed method is in the [Model]ContextInitializer, what is the best practice of the two?
I did understand that the Migration is a little better in terms of updating the DataBase with the `Enable-Migrations` `Add-Migration MyTitle` and `Update-Database` commands in Package Manager Console.
If this is a silly question, I beg you pardon me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migration `Seed` method is for seeding data right after database migration and DB Initializer `Seed` method is for seeding data right after Database initialization.

You can use Db Initialize `Seed` method to add initial data to DB right after **Initialization**, but you can use Migration `Seed` method to check and/or add new data or do special things right after **Migration**.

It can be a little bit confusing but if you think about it, you will understand it well. These are different cases.